# Raspberry pi:convert fisheye image to normal image using python

Tags: python, windows, image, camera

I have attached the USB webcam with raspberry pi to capture image and write code to send it using mail. It captures image using `fswebcam` commamnd so code for capture image in python script is :

```
subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam","-r 640x480", "image4.jpg"])
```

when I pressed switch from raspberry pi it capture image and sends it using mail,but problem is that captured image is fisheye image and iIwant to convert this fisheye image into normal image but I don't know the command for it or any code to convert it into normal image using python in raspberry pi? Thanks.This is my code:

```
import smtplib
import time
import subprocess
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Define these once; use them twice!
strFrom = 'user.example@gmail.com'
strTo = 'user.example@gmail.com'

#create email
# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subj$
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart()
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'capture image'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
print "press button to send email"
GPIO.setup(4,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
while True:
        input=GPIO.input(4)
        if input == False:
                print "button pressed"
                subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam","-r 640x480", "image4.jpg"])
                time.sleep(5)
                # This example assumes the image is in the current directory
                fp = open('image4.jpg', 'rb')
                msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
                fp.close()

                msgRoot.attach(msgImage)
                # send mail
                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                s.starttls()
                s.login('user.example@gmail.com' , 'password')
                s.sendmail(strFrom, strTo, msgRoot.as_string())
                s.close()
                print "Email sent"
                time.sleep(0.2)
```

---

so how to add solution provided in this both link : https://github.com/kscottz/dewarp and http://www.kscottz.com/dewarped-panoramic-images-from-a-raspberrypi-camera-module/ in to my above code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help :
http://www.kscottz.com/dewarped-panoramic-images-from-a-raspberrypi-camera-module/

this is the corresponding repo :
https://github.com/kscottz/dewarp

Comment: Thank u,this may be right but plz check above code that i have attched now and plz tell me how to add this solution privided by u add into that code. plz read again my above question bcaz i have edited it and give me solution if u have.