# Raspberrypi:remove fisheye effect from image

Tags: python, windows, opencv, numpy, raspberry-pi

I have raspberry pi and i generate code using python. That code captures a fisheye image, now I want a simple image, not a fisheye image. How do I remove that fisheye effect from the image or covert it into a simple image? I referred to some OpenCV site but couldn't find a solution..plz help me..Thanks in advance.

Comment: the keywords for your search are "camera calibration" and "lens distortion correction"

Comment: that i have already serched but it shows chessboard image that i don't need and i need to capture image and then convert ..i think it is not possible with it..

Comment: you use the chrssboard pattern fot calibration and lens distortion correction. after you've done that you can use that data to remove the fisheye effect in all your camera's images.

Comment: thank u micka,but i don't have idea that how to run calibrate.py file...if i run than file then and then i get RMS,camera matrix and distortion coefficient right? and also in that file written parameter left*.jpg what is it?and also written  cv2.imwrite('%s/%s_chess.bmp' % (debug_dir, name), vis) what is meaning of this line?what is chess.bmp?for run this file what line i have to write?

Comment: you have to create such a chessboard pattern yourself and show it to the camera. See answer of Francesco Nazzaro, the tutorial is quite ok and probably explains most of your questions.

Comment: that i don't know how to create chessboard pattern..i already refered that link..try that solution..but doesn't get any output i have also searched on for to create pattern for chessboard  but don't get any idea..plz provide me the code from that i can get solution and also tell me that how to run it becaz mainly i dont know how to run the seuence of code which image we have to need for code in which folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raspberry pi:convert fisheye image to normal image using python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369550/raspberry-piconvert-fisheye-image-to-normal-image-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this [LINK](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html#calibration) you can find a useful tutorial for camera calibration in OpenCV.

It explains you the chessboard method to correct fish-eye distortions.
After calibration you can correct all pictures taken by camera.

Comment: thank u,but i don't have idea how to write the code which is provided in this link..i have written cv2.drawChessboardCorners() portin of code and run it it is running without error but nothing show as output once i run this cv2.drawChessboardCorners() portion then after what code run next?

Comment: `cv2.calibrateCamera` provides camera matrix, distortion coefficients, rotation and translation vectors. You have to execute all the tutorial

Comment: cv2.calibrateCamera,cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix and  cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap have to write after cv2.destroyAllWindows()line in code? and in this file what is glob.glob('*.jpg')? need to change this line to our captured image like glob.glob('image4.jpg')?i have written this all in code shown in above link one after another only in one file is it correct right?so after executing in this way i got error like..cv2.error: /root/opencv-2.4.10/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3415: error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function calibrateCamera..so how to solve this error?

Comment: `glob.glob('*.jpg')` is to execute `cv2.findChessboardCorners` on all the chessboard images.

Comment: yes. `cv2.calibrateCamera`, `cv2.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix` and `cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap` must be execute after `cv2.destroyAllWindows`. anyway the code part below the comment `# Draw and display the corners` it's only for visualize.

Comment: so after executing this code getting error like cv2.error: /root/opencv-2.4.10/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3415: error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function calibrateCamera..so how to solve this error?

Comment: i don't know what you executed

Comment: above code given in link,i have written in calibrate.py file..now what syntex use to run it?sudo python calibrate.py or sudo python calibrate.py image.jpg or any other syntax?plz tell me the syntex..

Comment: this is off topic, i suggest you to use jupyter (http://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/what_is_jupyter.html) to test your calibration instead of a script.

Comment: if you want to build a command line try click (http://click.pocoo.org/5/)